# MySQL extract multiple values from Strings in each row?

Tags: mysql

Scenario:
I have Strings like the following in each row in my table. They may contain more than two placeholders which are enclosed by curly braces.

“Random Text {{placeholder}} {{placeholder.two}}”
“more random {{placeholder.three}} text for demo purposes {{placeholder.four}}”

Is it possible to extract all those place holders with a query in order to return a list of all existing placeholders in the column? I have tried it with TRIM() but that would only display one place holder per row

Comment: You can use [`REGEX_INSTR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-instr)

Comment: sure you can as long as you find a algorithm that can extract them

Comment: There's an `occurrence` optional parameter. To get multiple matches, call it with different occurrence values.

Comment: Personally I would say that it's likely easier to just do that on the application side, as you'll end up with either one column of many placeholders, or having to generate a finite and arbitrary number of columns (which always leaves room for a new string to break it with too many placeholders)

Comment: Actually, `REGEX_SUBSTR()` would be better. It also has an `occurrence` parameter.

Comment: `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` needs at least 8.0.4. If the version is older then nested `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` will solve.